# How can I show flash messages in code igniter in green?

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am using the following code in CodeIgnitor.

```
$data["flash_Message"] = "Update successfull."
```

I want to show the flash_Message in green. How can I do that?

Comment: This is something to do with HTML and CSS not with CodeIgniter. You can include the message in a html element and style that. Eg <div class='styled'><?php echo $flash_Message;?></div> then apply style to .styled in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this in your view :

```
if(isset($flash_Message))
{
  echo "<div style='color:green;'>$flash_Message<div>";
}
```

Personally, I used `flashdata` of codeigniter `session` library in displaying such successful/failure status...

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message',"<div style='color:green;'>Update successfull.<div>");
```

In view, you can display your `flashdata` in following way:

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your view file

```
if(isset($flash_Message)){
    <div><strong>Hey!</strong> <?php echo  $flash_Message ?> </div>
}
```

Or if you are using Jquery UI
use this code:

```
if(isset($flash_Message)){
  <div class='ui-widget'>
  <div class='ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all' style='margin-top:20px; padding:0 .7em;'>
  <p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-info' style='float: left; margin-right: .3em;'></span>
    <strong>Hey!</strong> <?php echo $flash_Message ?> </p>
  </div>
  </div>
   }
```

read more about Jquery UI from here http://jqueryui.com/